# How to compare to string in java?

Tags: java, jsp, bufferedreader, filereader

Hi i am truing to read data from a file and then i want to compare that string from my string 
i that string is equal to my string  then run if condition otherwise else condition

**My.jsp**

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<html>
<body>


       <%
           String s1="1";
          // int i=4;
           // String s=null;
          // String s2="1";
           String s3=null;
            String file = application.getRealPath("/") + "data.txt";
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){

                s3=line.toString();
            }

  if(s3.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))
      %>
     <%@ include file="MarketWiseData.jsp" %>
     <%else
  {%>
      <%@ include file="CommodityWise.jsp" %>
<%
          }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i get my target ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: i know that how to compare but i dont know  where i am wrong

Comment: @san Krish  i am getting (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: If you are getting NullPointerException, Reader object is not created, that means file is not present.

Comment: Even after while loop, if line variable is null, it will give NullPointerException.

Comment: by the way, having java code in JSP isn't a good practice. Read http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get `java.lang.NullPointerException` at the line `if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))`, because in your while loop, you have a check if `line != null`, and until the line is not null, your loop executing and when the `line=null`, code exit from loop and your if Condition occurs in which you checked `if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))` and since `line=null`, so you will get `NullPointerException` at your if condition.

I think you want this :

```
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))
     out.println("Shkati");
  else
  {
  out.println("sharma");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read your code:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // sb.append(line+"\n");
    out.println(line);
}

if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))
    out.println("Shkati");
else {
    out.println("sharma");
}
```

You have a while loop that keeps running while `line` is not null. It thus stops when `line` is null. So, in the `if` test, `line` is guaranteed to be null. And the test is thus guaranteed to throw a NullPointerException, since calling a method on null doesn't make sense.

Note that if, as in my code above, your code was properly indented, you would be able to immediately see its structure and logic. Failing to indent your code makes it confusing and unclear for yourself.